# is there any way to see the entrypont command in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am using entrypoint to start my app, now I use a variable in entrypoint and passed this variable in kubernetes pod env variable when running, this is my docker file:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

MAINTAINER jiangxiaoqiang (jiangtingqiang@gmail.com)

ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8 \
    LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 \
    TZ=Asia/Shanghai


RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime \
    && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone \
    && apk add --no-cache curl jq procps

ADD soa-service/build/libs/soa-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /root/soa-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
ADD script/start-docker.sh /root/start-docker.sh

EXPOSE 11005

ENTRYPOINT exec java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx256M -Xms128M \
                -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,suspend=n,server=y,address=5007 \
                -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/data/dump \
                -javaagent:/opt/skywalking/agent/skywalking-agent.jar=agent.service_name=soa-service \
                -Dskywalking.agent.service_name=soa-service \
                -Dskywalking.collector.backend_service=$SKYWALKING_ADDR \
                -jar /root/soa-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

and pass kubernetes env variable in yaml like this:

```
"env": [
                    {
                        "name": "SKYWALKING_ADDR",
                        "value": "10.106.251.29:11800"
                    }]
```

now the question is I am not sure this configuration works fine. I want to see the variable is  passed successfully.what should I do to see the startup command of entrypoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find your pod name using

`kubectl get pods`

Log into the running pod and execute bash:

`kubectl exec -it yourpodname bash`

Execute `ps` command with `-aux` to see more details on running processes and filter for java

`ps -aux | grep java`

Example output:

`cnb            1  0.1  8.4 456540 171884 ?       Ssl  Jun13   3:28 java -cp /workspace -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=40M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=60M -Xlog:gc -Xms36m -Xmx40m -Xss256k -XX:MaxRAM=150M -Djava.security.properties=/layers/paketo-buildpacks_bellsoft-liberica/java-security-properties/java-security.properties -agentpath:/layers/paketo-buildpacks_bellsoft-liberica/jvmkill/jvmkill-1.16.0-RELEASE.so=printHeapHistogram=1 -XX:ActiveProcessorCount=2 -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher`